# C# Console XML files failing validation in certain sequence

Tags: c#, xml

I have a C# console application that processes XML files in batches. It grabs a batch from a folder, processes each batch one by one, then stops, restarts and repeats. It also checks the batches for errors, either XML validation or missing files. If errors occur the folders move to an "error" folder. Simple enough.

The application was tested with 100 batches, or 10,000 files, and performed fine and fast when no error batches occurred. In general, it runs fine about 98% of the time.

There is 1 circumstance I have not been able to figure out yet. It appears that when an error batch occurs and then a good batch comes after it, the good batch fails an XML validation and then does not write its batch to the database.

The trip-up happens in the following code block. Prior to this, a while(di.GetFiles("*.xml").Length > 0) keeps processing batches until none remain. If no validation error occur, then the code enters the block below. Things seems to go strange right away with the try/catch of the XML.Load - sometimes this fails and the very last else statement executes. Even stranger, if the files that failed get resubmitted they process just fine. So I'm wondering if there is a speed issue here that may overwhelm XDocument or perhaps I should be using XmlReader here instead, or could an already open XDocument cause something like this?

```
  foreach (var file in filesToValidate)
{
    var xml = new XDocument();

    try
    {
        xml = XDocument.Load(file);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        batchErrorsString += string.Format("Batch {0} has an invalid XML file and needs to be resubmitted: {1}<br>", batchNum, file);
    }

    if (batchErrorsString.Length == 0)
    {
       var importThing = xml.Descendants("import_thing").Any();
       var importThing2 = xml.Descendants("import_thing2").Any();
       var Code = "";
       var fileDr = "";
       var fileRc = "";                        

        if (importThing)
        {
            Code = xml.Descendants("import_dnr").Select(x => x.Element("code").Value).FirstOrDefault();
            fileDr = xml.Descendants("row").Select(x => x.Element("key").Value).FirstOrDefault();
            fileRc = xml.Descendants("row").Select(x => x.Element("grp").Value).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            Code = xml.Descendants("import_race").Select(x => x.Element("code").Value).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        var objectType = importDnr ? "THING" : "THING2";
        var userName = Environment.UserName;

        // create record and populate table
        var objectToUpload = _servImp.CreateImportRequestRecord(file, Ids, xml, objectType, Code, userName);
        var iid = _repo.InsertTable(objectToUpload);    

    }
    else
    {
        _servEmail.SendMail(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorMailTo"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorMailFrom"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorMailCC"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorMailSubject"], string.Format("Batch {0} is invalid - resubmit", batchNum), "");
        }                                        
    }
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: "Prior to this, a `while(di.GetFiles("*.xml").Length > 0)` keeps processing batches until none remain." Why not just fetch the list of files *once* and process them all? That sounds far less worrying in terms of seeing "half" changes to files etc.

Comment: If possible please post the exception details once the error happens plus its stack trace.

Comment: Shouldn't you clear batchErrorsString variable once current file is processed? Since batchErrorsString is declared outside for loop, it will retain value from last iteration and will not execute if block for current iteration.

Comment: @PankajKapare so the next question is are you still getting an email when the good batch fails xml validation?

Comment: @JonSkeet - yes, that would be easier, but each batch needs to get checked for completeness and other errors and processing them all at once made that complicated.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really follow that logic at all. It doesn't help that you haven't told us what the exception is - and indeed you appear to be not even logging that...

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko  - strangely, I haven't seen the actual exception yet - the files just fail in the try/catch and no exception - I altered to code to catch that, but I didn't post that version, but perhaps that's something to try again?

Comment: @GibralterTop - yes, the entire application works great except for this glitch - other e-mails are sent as expected

Comment: @PankajKapare - can you elaborate on that? Are you saying that the batchErrors variable might cause the if block to not execute?

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone. Sorry I don't yet have the exception, but I'm rolling out some code that should log it. I'll update my post when I have it (it relies on the situation happening again, because I haven't been able to replicate it).

Comment: @ewomack: Suppose you are processing xyz.xml file. For some reason XmlDocument.Load fails then catch block will set "batchErrorsString" variable. Suppose next file is abc.xml, load method loads document however since length of batchErrorsString content is more than 0 which was set during xyz.xml file processing "IF" block will not get executed.

Comment: @PankajKapare to sum up: you need to add `batchErrorsString = "";` after your `_servEmail.SendMail()` line. Or you can put your code that is in your `if (batchErrorsString.Length == 0)` inside your `try` and your `else` code inside your `catch` so you can keep your `batchErrorsString` if you have to use it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Pankaj Kapere's comment, you are not clearing your `batchErrorsString`. Which means once you hit an error, the subsequent batches will be in error. There are two ways to fix this.

Method 2 allows you to continue using the `batchErrorsString` if you want to do something with it after you are done processing whereas Method 1 clears the value every file.

Method 1:

```
foreach (var file in filesToValidate)
{
    var xml = new XDocument();

    try
    {
        xml = XDocument.Load(file);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        batchErrorsString += string.Format("Batch {0} has an invalid XML file and needs to be resubmitted: {1}<br>", batchNum, file);
    }

    if (batchErrorsString.Length == 0)
    {
        //your working code
    }
    else
    {
        _servEmail.SendMail(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorMailTo"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorMailFrom"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorMailCC"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorMailSubject"], string.Format("Batch {0} is invalid - resubmit", batchNum), "");

        batchErrorsString = ""; //Clear here
    }                                        
}
```

Method 2:

```
foreach (var file in filesToValidate)
{
    var xml = new XDocument();

    try
    {
        xml = XDocument.Load(file);
        var importThing = xml.Descendants("import_thing").Any();
        var importThing2 = xml.Descendants("import_thing2").Any();
        var Code = "";
        var fileDr = "";
        var fileRc = "";                        

        if (importThing)
        {
            Code = xml.Descendants("import_dnr").Select(x => x.Element("code").Value).FirstOrDefault();
            fileDr = xml.Descendants("row").Select(x => x.Element("key").Value).FirstOrDefault();
            fileRc = xml.Descendants("row").Select(x => x.Element("grp").Value).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            Code = xml.Descendants("import_race").Select(x => x.Element("code").Value).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        var objectType = importDnr ? "THING" : "THING2";
        var userName = Environment.UserName;

        // create record and populate table
        var objectToUpload = _servImp.CreateImportRequestRecord(file, Ids, xml, objectType, Code, userName);
        var iid = _repo.InsertTable(objectToUpload); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        batchErrorsString += string.Format("Batch {0} has an invalid XML file and needs to be resubmitted: {1}<br>", batchNum, file);
        _servEmail.SendMail(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorMailTo"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorMailFrom"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorMailCC"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorMailSubject"], string.Format("Batch {0} is invalid - resubmit", batchNum), "");
    }                                     
}
```